# Live Timer // Parse & Swift

Tags: parse-platform, timer, swift2

Im trying to figure out how can I do a live 30 second timer which every 30 second something happens. No matter who opens the app the timer will continue to run even if you just open the app and the timer might be on 20s or 10s or even 1s. And right when it hits zero, I have something that pops up.

I have it done but it's a timer that starts when the app is view is opened and always starts from 30s and if someone else opens the app he also starts from 30s i want it so that who ever opens the view the timer is still running.

Comment: Just the users and scores. Nothing related to time. I wanted to know how I should start. If it's even possible. @Wain

Comment: The server could return a 'next fire' date that the app uses. That date could be calculated in a cloud code function.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out. Thanks!